# Encrypt a single key in the appsettings section of App.Config file

Tags: c#, .net, encryption, app-config

Is it possible to encrypt a single value or must you encrypt entire sections?

I.e. Given the app.config below can how can I encrypt just the password. I've read articles on encrypting connection string sections and whole sections of app.config.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
<appSettings>
<add key="Interval" value="40000" />
<add key="User" value="User1" />
<add key="Password" value="boombox" />    ...
```

If you have any suggestions they would be greatly appreciated

Comment: You can always encrypt it yourself, store it in encrypted form, and decrypt it when needed; but there is no direct support for this in the .NET configuration system (that only works on a per-section basis)

Comment: Thanks, yeah thats the obvious part i left out of my question. Whether, as you put it, there was direct support in the .net config system to do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to encrypt/decrypt before saving/after loading the settings file. Look at the [System.Security.Cryptography Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eat8fht.aspx). I used the DES provider to read/write a password into the settings file.

Answer (score 1):

You can encrypt a password in an app.config by using [DPAPI](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgalloway/archive/2008/04/13/encrypting-passwords-in-a-net-app-config-file.aspx).

Comment: note Jon's solution only works on a single machine - moving the application & configuration to another breaks the encryption

Comment: DPAPI can encrypt and decrypt a string, but the encrypted characters are illegal for the App.Config's XML. This is being added to prevent future readers from wasting time on it.